# Feedback diode question

Tags: power-supply, diodes, feedback, flyback

In the following circuit the explanation of D1 says:
[image]
“D1 connected across the input to output terminals is for protection and prevents the regulator from being reverse biased when the input supply voltage is switched OFF while the output supply remains ON or active for a short period of time due to a large inductive load such as a solenoid or motor.”

Questions that come up:

- Is the “feedback” diode acting as a “fly back” diode if there’s an inductive load on the output? If so does this voltage just dissipate across the diode? Wouldn’t it also go back into the input supply and cause damage?
- Is D2 acting as protection to the rest of the circuit in the case of reverse voltage coming in at the output? If so it’s relying on whatever is connected at the output to have a built in fuse of some sort to cut constant power?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the writer there was conflating two issues.  D2 would be the likely saviour of the part due to inductive loads, since the current would continue to flow in the same direction and would pull the positive rail below ground.  D1 is there to prevent the part from being reverse biased as a result of a sudden loss of input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the “feedback” diode acting as a “fly back” diode if there’s an
>   inductive load on the output?

No it isn't. See this note from TI in their LM317 regulator data sheet: -

[image]

See this from ST: -

[image]

> Is D2 acting as protection to the rest of the circuit in the case of
>   reverse voltage coming in at the output?

It would do this.

Comment: It can act as a Flyback to the input , but I recall the designers app note indicated the output Darlington stage has something like a -5V VIO. Thus a sudden input shutoff to 0V could reverse the output stage , so the diode pulls down the output with a sudden input drop faster than the output.  But an inductive Flyback could inject the same reverse bias without D1 as the output is just an emitter follower with negative feedback.

Comment: If say a solenoid we’re connected to the output and was taking (say) 100 mA, upon disconnecting the solenoid, to keep the same current flowing, the positive connection (the one that is disconnected) will drop rapidly negative and not positive. D2 (Ops drawing) would save the day and not D1. @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75

Answer (score 0):

It is there to prevent the input from becoming too much lower of a voltage than the output. If the input gets too low vs the output, the internals can become damaged.

Other regulator types may not be susceptible to being damaged when reverse driven and thus not need a diode.

Answer (score 0):

The diode adds a path for reverse current in case when applied voltage to the output is higher than regulator voltage. The reverse current would flow also without that diode, but the LM317 isn't designed for that, so this reverse current would overheat the silicon and burn the LM317, so that's why the reverse diode is added.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the “feedback” diode acting as a “fly back” diode if there’s an inductive load on the output? If so does this voltage just dissipate across the diode? Wouldn’t it also go back into the input supply and cause damage?

**No**

The quote you included explains it well;

> “D1 connected across the input to output terminals is for protection and prevents the regulator from being reverse biased when the input supply voltage is switched OFF while the output supply remains ON or active for a short period of time due to a large inductive load such as a solenoid or motor.”

What is it about this that you don't understand?

The output has a capacitor which gets charged up, if you remove power from the input you end up in a cituation where the voltage on the output is higher than the voltage on the input, due to the capacitor on the output, and most LDO's can't handle that.

In the case of an inductive load you need a separate freewheeling-diode, D1 will not protect you in that case, it would be reverse biased.

> Is D2 acting as protection to the rest of the circuit in the case of reverse voltage coming in at the output? If so it’s relying on whatever is connected at the output to have a built in fuse of some sort to cut constant power?

**Kind of**

D2 is a freewheeling-diode, IT will protect you against inductive discharging in the case of an inductive load. It could also protect you against reverse polarity on the output if such a cenario is likely in your application, but then you are correct in assuming that you would need some over-current protection as well, although outputs are rarely reverse polarity protected as this doesn't make sense in most applications.

Comment: Thank you.  For some reason I wasn’t thinking that the “output” of the regulator would become the input in a reverse polarity situation. I was caught up in the operation of D2 doing same job as D1 and overlooked the different orientation of the two. So the voltage then would dissipate through D1, the capacitors, and resistors to ground bypassing the regulator?

Answer (score 0):

D1 protects the regulator if the input voltage is **shorted** or there is a **heavy load** on the input when it is turned off. Otherwise the output capacitor(s) will discharge through the parasitic diode and transistors in the regulator and the current might be high enough to damage the regulator. It does not take the place of a flyback diode across an inductive load.

D2 is there to prevent externally applied voltage from driving the output negative. Any such current is assumed to be externally limited or D2 could be destroyed. A real-life example of such a situation is a possible fault or start-up condition when you connect two such supplies in series to get a bipolar supply.